# Design and Implementation of ClojureScript

Tags: clojure

My question is NOT about how to use ClojureScript to produce JavaScript code.

I am interested in ClojureScript because it implements Clojure \ {eval} within Clojure, and is able to compile it to another language. Thus, I'm interested in the possibility of having ClojureScript target other platforms.

Question: besides the source code, is the Design & Implementation of ClojureScript documented anywhere? I'd like a high level overview of how the various parts of the compiler work together:
  * how are the

Comment: just curious - why would you want to do that? The whole point of ClojureScript is to target JavaScript, if you want to target any other platform then Clojure itself is a better choice (since it will run anywhere with a JVM.....)

Comment: @mikera, I believe ClojureScript is being developed with the idea that eventually you can plug in different target platforms. There's even a Google Summer of Code project that is doing exactly that. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/clojure-dev/gxXcIHyEcak

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as the documentation for "Clojurescript pipeline and how you can hook into it" is concerned you can check out [this](http://blog.fogus.me/2012/04/25/the-clojurescript-compilation-pipeline/) blog entry.